# Access .net DLL from Java

Tags: java, .net, dll, jna, metatrader4

I am new to **`java`** and DLL-s

I need to access DLL's methods from `java`. So go easy on me.

I have tried using JNA to access the DLL here is what I have done.

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;

public class mapper {

  public interface mtApi extends Library {
        public boolean IsStopped();
  }

  public static void main(String []args){
     mtApi lib = (mtApi) Native.loadLibrary("MtApi", mtApi.class);
     boolean test = lib.IsStopped();
     System.out.println(test);

  }
}
```

When I run the code, I am getting the following error:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:`
> `Error looking up function 'IsStopped':`
> `The specified procedure could not be found.`

I understand that this error is saying it cannot find the function, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I am trying to use this API [**`mt4api`**](http://mtapi4.net/)

and here is the method, I am attempting to access [**`MQL4`**](https://docs.mql4.com/check)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have looked at other alternatives, like `jni4net`, but I cannot get this working either.

If anyone can link me to a tutorial that shows me how to set this up, or knows how to, I would be greatfull.

Comment: I should mention that tutorial requests or off topic. Now, .net dlls are not callable directly, because they contain IL. I think you'd have to write a C++/CLI wrapper (which allows for managed and unmanaged code) and call that through JNA. I found [this website](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge/) that describes this problem.

Comment: Brillant thank you for the advice, ill take a look now

Comment: Ok so i have now found 2 ways of bridging which i am going to try, creating my own bridge [creating bridge](http://codefry.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html) or using jni4net [http://jni4net.com/](http://jni4net.com/) I was wondering if you know which solution would be faster, speed is essential as i'm trading on the forex market both prgrammes need to talk in as little milliseconds as possible.

Comment: In that case, It would be faster to just write the application in C#. You have to go from Java to native, which is expensive, then from native to IL, which is also expensive. After that I guess things could be inlined, but I don't know that much about the .net JIT. Maybe you can find a similar API for Java as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Trading?
Hunting for milliseconds to shave-off?
Go rather into Distributed Processing... <sub>Definitely safer than relying on API !</sub>

While your OP was directed onto how bend `java` to call .NET DLL-functions,
**let me sketch a much future-safer solution**.

Using AI/ML-regression based predictors for FOREX trading, I was hunting in the same forest. The best solution found within the last about 12-years, having spent about a few hundreds man*years of experience, was setup in the following manner:

<kbd>`Host A`</kbd> executes trades: operates MetaTrader Terminal 4, with both Script and EA --- the [**distributed-processing system  communicates with with a use of `ZeroMQ` low-latency messaging/signalling framework**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D) ( about a few tens of microseconds needed )

<kbd>`Host B`</kbd> executes AI/ML processing of predictions for a traded instrument ( about a few hundreds of microseconds apply )

<kbd>`Cluster C`</kbd> executes continuous AI/ML predictor re-trainings and HyperParameterSPACE model selections ( many CPU-hours indeed needed, continuous model self-adapting process running 24/7 )

---

Signalling / Messaging layer with `ZeroMQ` has ports and/or bindings available and ready for most of the mainstream and many of niche programming languages, including `java`.

### Hidden dangers of going just against a published API:

While the efforts for system integration and testing are immense, the API specifications are always dangerous for specification creeping.

This said, add countless man*months consumed on debugging after a silent change in MT4 language specifications that de-rail your previous tools + libraries. Why? Just imagine. Some time ago, `MQL4` stopped to be `MQL4` and was silently shifted towards `MQL5`, under a name ***New*-`MQL4`**. Among other changes in compilation, there were many small and big nails in the coffin -- **`string`** surprisingly ceased to be a `string` and was hidden as an internal **`struct`** -- which one could guess what will cause with all DLL-calls.

So, beware of API creepings.

---

### Does it hurt a distributed processing solution?

No.

With a wise message-layout design, there are no adverse effects of MetaTrader Terminal 4 behaviour and all the logic ( incl. the strategy decision ) is put outside this creeping platform.

Doable. Fast and smart. Also could use remote-GPU-cluster processing, if your budget allows.

---

### Does it work even in Strategy Tester?

Yes, it does.

If anyone has the gut to rely on the in-built Strategy Tester, the distributed-processing model still works there. Performance depends on the preferred style of modelling, a full one year, tick-by-tick simulation, with a quite complex AI/ML components took a few days on a common COTS desktops PC-systems ( after years of Quant R&D, we do not use Strategy Tester internally at all, but the request was to batch-test the y/y tick-data, so could be commented here ).

Comment: Great answer thank you. I may have a few further questions soon, would it be ok to pm you?

Comment: Glad it helped, Jay. Feel free to go ahead.

Comment: I have some questions already how can i contact you ^_^ thank you for agreeing to talk to me personally, i really appreciate it.